# Accessing multiple Office 365 accounts from OWA

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, outlook-web-access

I like accessing Email through the OWA web access method.  It lets me have just another Chrome tab with my Email without having to install Outlook or another Email client on my machine.  So I have a very lightweight install and just open Chrome with all my tabs including Email.

This has worked well with a single Office 365 account.  I recently added another Office 365 account with a different organization.

I noticed the below URL format.

https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=someorganization.com

I thought I would be clever and just have two different Chrome tabs, opened using links where the above is replaced with the appropriate organization.

This doesn't work.  Once you're logged into the one account in OWA, the other tab just logs into the same account, ignoring the realm argument.

So it doesn't appear that you can have 2 Chrome tabs, each logged into a different organization's Office 365 account.

One workaround is to open a Chrome incognito window and login to the second organization with that, but this is more cumbersome than the initial goal of having them both as regular tabs which auto open when you launch Chrome.

I thought maybe OWA would have a way to add multiple accounts, but it seems completely tied to a single account.

Searching on this yielded another possibility of shared folders, however, I tried that and it doesn't look like it will let you share folders across different organizations.

Has anyone figured out a clever way to get at different accounts in different tabs in a single Chrome browser instance?  I'd like to avoid installing Outlook or another Email client if possible.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. Incognito mode is the only method I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two approaches here.

1. Use an incognito window, this provides isolation of the session and lets you open a different organization's account in the other window.  But, when you close the window nothing is saved (as its incognito) so you have to go through the login and 2 factor auth each time (if you use that)
2. In Chrome, add another user.  In the second user, which opens a separate window also, login to the other organization.  This has the advantage over #1 that it can be saved and let you just open it again and be right back at the second Email account.